# Sendgird Web API python example code not working: 401 unauthorized

Tags: python, django, heroku, sendgrid

The problem:
Sendgrid web api python example code showing error 401: Unauthorized

The settings:
server-heroku, framework-django, sendgrid single sender authorized but not domain. Heroku add-on attached.

The code:
/sendgrid.env:`export SENDGRID_API_KEY='the api key'`
/view.py

```
def Contact(request):
    message = Mail(
        from_email='customerservice@shionhouse.net',
        to_emails='to@example.com',
        subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
        html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')

    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)

    return render(request, 'core/contact.html')
```

By the way, is sendgrid really worth awhile? Or is it just better off using django default SMTP anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` is either invalid or your API access is simply not authorized to do such action.

Under quickstart: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-python/

you find the following pre-requisites:

> - Sign up for a SendGrid account
> - Create and store a SendGrid API Key with full access "Mail Send" permissions.
> - Verify your Sender Identity
> - Install Python

Did you verify the Sender Identity?

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/